# How to sort a string from bigger to smaller

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, sorting, vector

`res` is `string` but I can't sort. `res.begin(), res.end()` is not working, What I should do?

```
//for example:
input:   a = 13; b = 17
sort before : 1314151617
sort after : 1111134567
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void test3 () {
   int a, b;
   cin >> a >> b;
   int l =0;
   string res;
   for (int i=a; i<=b; i++) {
     res = res + to_string(a + l);
     l++;
   }
sort (res.begin(), res.end());
}
int main () {
  test3();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: for input `13 1` the `for` loop does not run, because `13 <= 1` is false. So, you sort an empty string. How do you know that it does not work? You do not print the string before and afterwards.

Comment: The ```sort()``` function works, there's an issue with the input method above it

Comment: @mch OP wants it in descending order.

Comment: From your title, `std::sort (res.rbegin(), res.rend());` or better `std::sort (res.begin(), res.end(), std::greater<>{});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comparator. By default C++ sorts elements based on the `<` operator. If you want to sort elements in descending order, you use the same code, but provide an extra comparator:

```cpp
std::string s = "12341532231858092";
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<char>()); // notice the 3rd argument!
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

prints `98855433322221110`.